# remesh grid not showing

Tags: sculpting, remesh

I'm using Blender 4.0 and I'm trying to remesh my object to sculpt. However, when I try to do this, nothing shows up. I am in sculpting mode, and I'm pressing R or Shift R but I only get the resize option. Ive tried to do this on my laptop (mac) aswell and it does show me a grid. So what am I missing on my pc?

*edit I use industry compatible

Comment: R is to set the grid size, Ctrl R is to apply the remesh, it should work

Comment: if the shortcut is not the same, go into the Preferences > Keymap > Name > type Voxel Remesh or Edit Voxel Size and check what is the shortcut

Comment: `Shift`+`R` is in _Sculpt Mode_ as well as in other modes _Repeat Last_, so it does not really do anything apparently if you used `R` before. For remeshing the shortcuts are like @moonboots already said, `R` for setting the grid size, `Ctrl`+`R` to remesh to the grid size... if you did not change the keymap from the defaults to something else. You might not necessarily have done this yourself intentionally, sometimes third-party addons change shortcuts for some reason.

Comment: Ctrl R might be Cmd R on MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

After searching around I found out my default shortcut for the remesh is <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> for Windows. I changed this in the keymap settings.